# Downsizing non-representative data in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

folks,
I occasionally dabble in **pandas** - but I cannot claim deep knowledge. Today I had to filter out some rows from a **DataFrame** based on occurence of a value in a certain column. E.g., in this simplified example

```
In [57]: table = pd.DataFrame([[2, 'a'], [3, 'b'], [2, 'c'], [4, 'd'], [4, 'e'], [5, 'f']], 
...:                      columns=('group', 'letter'))
...: print(table)
...:                      
   group letter
0      2      a
1      3      b
2      2      c
3      4      d
4      4      e
5      5      f
```

I want to filter out rows with a value in the *group* column that appears only once in the *DataFrame*.

I hacked around the problem by this inellegant solution (again, this is only an example)

```
In [58]: pd.concat(df for _, df in table.groupby(by=['group']) if len(df) > 1)
Out[58]: 
   group letter
0      2      a
2      2      c
3      4      d
4      4      e
```

But I bet there are proper ways to achieve the same goal.

Anyone can suggest a more pandaic  solution?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size as original df, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
table = table[table.groupby(by=['group'])['letter'].transform('size') > 1]
print(table)
   group letter
0      2      a
2      2      c
3      4      d
4      4      e
```

**Detail**:

```
print(table.groupby(by=['group'])['letter'].transform('size'))
0    2
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    1
Name: letter, dtype: int64
```

Another solution with [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) in large DataFrame should be slowier:

```
table = table.groupby(by=['group']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just curious - is _groupby_ the only way?!

Comment: @volcano - in pandas yes. Problem is really big data?

Comment: @jezsrael - not teally, about 4400 by 5, and it was an interactive session. But I wanted to learn a better way. Thanks again!